# texture stretching

Tags: texturing, uv

I am using the blender to do modeling and UV unwrapping, rendering in general. Also, I am new to blender. For texturing, I use Substance painter. Recently I faced an issue with texturing. I placed some decals to the model in substance painter and they are looking what it is should be, but when I assigned the exported texture back in the blender it is stretched. This is a low poly object. I looked for the solution, non of they are not helping. Can you all plz help

[image: exported base color in substance]

[image: look in substance painter]

Comment: 1) No modifiers in Blender, which can stretch things.  2) Triangulate models before painting in SP.  Not sure if those are the causes of your problem, but they could be.

Comment: thanks Nathan, I'll try you suggestions